# Sparse Rotation Matrix Python SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, rotational-matrices

I'm working with quite large rotation matrices, which have the inherent property to have a large number of zeros. In order to reduce memory use and possibly reduce computation cost when multiplying these rotation matrices with other matrices/vectors, I would like to use a sparse matrix data structure. I have found documentation on the SciPy sparse matrices, but I don't quite understand how these work and what the differences are. ([SciPy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html))

What would be the best sparse data structure to use for rotation matrices in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the rotation matrix as a dense array you can simply do

```
m = csr_matrix(dense_rot_matrix)
```

One of the two types `csr_matrix` or `csc_matrix` should be used.

A better option would be to populate already the sparse matrix which can be easily accomplished using the `coo_matrix` type, which has efficient methods to convert to `csr_matrix` or `csc_matrix`. [I've been using Cython to create sparse matrices in this way very efficiently](https://github.com/compmech/compmech/blob/master/compmech/conecyl/clpt/clpt_donnell_bc1_linear.pyx).

Comment: Thanks! :) One more question though; if I use either `csr_matrix` or `csc_matrix`, how should I multiply these by a vector (that is just a normal array) ? From what I see so far this cannot be done immediately right? EDIT: never mind, mistake in my code, my bad. Thanks again!

Comment: @danielvdende right, you can multiply simply by `m*a_ndarray_object` or using `m.dot(a_ndarray_object)`